How to disable red error popup message in TMS WEB Core websites?
Every time my website has an error, then I get a red error message popup at the bottom of my page.

Is it possible to remove or disable this error message?
I don't want to have the red error message appear even when there is an error happening.

The Error message can be configured via Application.ErrorType.
To disable the red message popup, simply add the following line of code at the beginning of your main form's OnCreate event:
Application.ErrorType := TApplicationErrorType.aeSilent;

You can also put it in your project's .dpr file after Application.Initialize such as here:
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.ErrorType := TApplicationErrorType.aeSilent;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.

